# Making a HTML Button rounded

Tags: html

I need to make the button rounded, however, can't use the `<input>` attribute as I already have a div with that, so i had to use the `<button type>` attribute. Here's what I've got:

```css
.button2 {
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="button2"> 
    <button type="button">Sign up</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change class to button, not button2, as that's changing the actual div which has no properties, and the button does.

```html
<div class="button">
    <button class="button">Sign Up</button>
</div>

<style>
.button {
  padding:0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align:center;
}  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a class to the input.

```
<input type="" class="whatever" />
input.whatever { border-radius:5px; }
```

Edit:
Actually if it's a sign-up button you probably want an

```
<a href="/sign-up" class="whatever" />Sign Up</a>
a.whatever { dislay:inline-block; border-radius:5px; padding:5px; }
```

Comment: I cannot add an input type!

Comment: You could do.. You just need a class to specify which you're targeting with your CSS. It would be awful if you could only use one input per page, ever.

Answer (score 0):

"[border-radius](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/border_radius/)" is the CSS property you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button2 {
  padding:0px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 10px;   <--- this rounds the corners
}
```